# MySQL order by slow

Tags: mysql, performance, order-by, query-performance

I have a table named 'customer' with the following structure and indexes:

```
DESCRIBE customer;
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| email              | varchar(70)   | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| orders             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| country            | text          | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_date_order    | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| first_date_order   | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| name               | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| lastname           | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| male               | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| gender_probability | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| phone              | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| phone_formatted    | varchar(20)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_at         | timestamp     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| updated_at         | timestamp     | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+

SHOW INDEX FROM customer;
 +----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| customer |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | id          | A         |     1899746 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| customer |          0 | email      |            1 | email       | A         |     1899746 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| customer |          1 | updated_at |            1 | updated_at  | A         |         200 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I can execute this query, which takes 15 seconds approximately:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE updated_at >= '2018-02-16 00:00:00';
931817 rows in set (14.33 sec)
```

And this is the same query but adding an `order by`:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE updated_at >= '2018-02-16 00:00:00' ORDER BY updated_at ASC;
931817 rows in set (5 min 21.17 sec)
```

I think 5 mins is too slow, the explain for the query shows:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM customer WHERE updated_at >= '2018-02-16 00:00:00' ORDER BY updated_at ASC;
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | customer | ALL  | updated_at    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1899744 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

The profile says this:

```
SET profiling = 1;
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE updated_at >= '2018-02-16 00:00:00' ORDER BY updated_at ASC;
SHOW PROFILE;
SET profiling = 0;

+------------------------------+------------+
| Status                       | Duration   |
+------------------------------+------------+
| Sending data                 |   0.036616 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000034 |
| Sending data                 |   0.088051 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000034 |
| Sending data                 |   0.064104 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000038 |
| Sending data                 |   0.045420 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000043 |
| Sending data                 |   0.035219 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000025 |
| Sending data                 |   0.049755 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000035 |
| Sending data                 |   0.069008 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000036 |
| Sending data                 |   0.068619 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000042 |
| Sending data                 |   0.067039 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000048 |
| Sending data                 |   0.051564 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000042 |
| Sending data                 |   0.052017 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000036 |
| Sending data                 |   0.049105 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000034 |
| Sending data                 |   0.060379 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000029 |
| Sending data                 |   0.118096 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000027 |
| Sending data                 |   0.046678 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000037 |
| Sending data                 |   0.058142 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000027 |
| Sending data                 |   0.137221 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000046 |
| Sending data                 |   0.061968 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000045 |
| Sending data                 |   0.054456 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000045 |
| Sending data                 |   0.054738 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000025 |
| Sending data                 |   0.073921 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000028 |
| Sending data                 |   0.040226 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000034 |
| Sending data                 |   0.036024 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000046 |
| Sending data                 |   0.063350 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000035 |
| Sending data                 |   0.044174 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000028 |
| Sending data                 |   0.057658 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000031 |
| Sending data                 |   0.081529 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000041 |
| Sending data                 |   0.074443 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000027 |
| Sending data                 |   0.058293 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000033 |
| Sending data                 |   0.061443 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000037 |
| Sending data                 |   0.075515 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000035 |
| Sending data                 |   0.075264 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000039 |
| Sending data                 |   0.049696 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000027 |
| Sending data                 |   0.052088 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000036 |
| Sending data                 |   0.049119 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000039 |
| Sending data                 |   0.053930 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000028 |
| Sending data                 |   0.064894 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000039 |
| Sending data                 |   0.046105 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000027 |
| Sending data                 |   0.061840 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000033 |
| Sending data                 |   0.065950 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000038 |
| Sending data                 |   0.053379 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000028 |
| Sending data                 |   0.034599 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000027 |
| Sending data                 |   0.046371 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000033 |
| Sending data                 |   0.039776 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000035 |
| Sending data                 |   0.046480 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000040 |
| Sending data                 |   0.039515 |
| Waiting for query cache lock |   0.000036 |
| Sending data                 | 405.206648 |
| end                          |   0.000040 |
| query end                    |   0.000011 |
| closing tables               |   0.000017 |
| freeing items                |   0.000036 |
| logging slow query           |   0.000006 |
| logging slow query           |   0.000011 |
| cleaning up                  |   0.000006 |
+------------------------------+------------+
100 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on why the `order by` impacts the performance so much? 15s to 5mins+ is a large jump.

EXPLAIN for the query of RolandoMySQLDBA

```
SELECT B.* FROM (SELECT id FROM customer WHERE updated_at >= '2018-02-16 00:00:00' ORDER BY updated_at ASC) A LEFT JOIN customer B USING (id);
932016 rows in set (6 min 6.39 sec)

+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL       | NULL    | NULL | 932025 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | B          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY    | 4       | A.id |      1 |                          |
|  2 | DERIVED     | customer   | range  | updated_at    | updated_at | 4       | NULL | 949956 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Is `SELECT *` necessary for your query, or can you get by with fewer columns? If so, which columns do you actually need?

Comment: I'm sending all data to a external service, I need them all.

Comment: @VictorCompany - Does the 'external service' need them in order?  What will they do with that mass of data?  Could it be done better inside MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have in the question

- `1899746` rows in the table
- `931817` rows > `2018-02-16 00:00:00`
- Index on `updated_at` has 200 distinct values

The EXPLAIN plan shows a full table scan and a sort of a temp table which has all columns. This makes sense since the WHERE clause sees 49.0496% of the table rows. It is easier to do a full table than figure out from the key distribution that accessing the index also requires accessing the table. This explains why the EXPLAIN plan did not choose the `updated_at` index.

The distribution of key values in the `updated_at` index can be seen by running this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) rowcount,updated_at FROM customer GROUP BY updated_at;
```

You could use the index to collect the ids first and then join them later

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(SELECT id FROM customer
WHERE updated_at >= '2018-02-16 00:00:00'
ORDER BY updated_at ASC) A
LEFT JOIN customer B USING (id);
```

If the subquery collecting the ids chooses the index, then the whole query may be fast. Please run the EXPLAIN on this and see if this is the case.

Comment: The failing of this, and the original post, is the "bouncing back and forth between the index and the data.

Comment: Newer versions of MySQL (and MariaDB) are permitted to ignore the `ORDER BY` in the derived table.  The logic is that a derived table delivers a "set", which has no order.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a crucial part of your application, you could change the `PRIMARY KEY` to start with `updated_at` (and change the existing primary key to a `UNIQUE` key/constraint):

```
-- table/index reconstruction
-- this will take some time
-- but only needs to be done once
ALTER TABLE customer
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
  DROP INDEX updated_at,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (updated_at, id),
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX id_uq (id) ;
```

The above change will make the clustering key of the table to be based on `updated_at`, so there will be 2 benefits for the query:

- do only a partial table scan,
- skip the sorting part, as the rows will be already sorted the way you want.

Comment: For more efficiency, the index on `id` can be simply `INDEX`, not `UNIQUE`.

Answer (score 2):

Some explanations...

```
SELECT * ... WHERE ...
```

The Optimizer sees that much of the table is needed, so it simply reads the data, ignoring the index.

```
SELECT * ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...
```

Now the Optimizer has a touch choice -- (1) Scan the table, then sort the million rows.  (2) Scan the index (to avoid the sort), but have to bounce between the index and the data.  Either way is costly.

```
SELECT ... FROM ( SELECT id ... ) JOIN ...
```

This just makes things worse because it now has to build a temp table with the million ids.  Nothing saved; extra stuff added.

```
PRIMARY KEY(updated_at, id)
```

By including `id`, the PK is unique (a requirement).  *Assuming that the table is InnoDB*, by *starting* the PK with `updated_at`, the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` are both satisfied by a "range" scan of the data.  And only part (about half) of the table needs to be scanned.

Profiling is essentially useless.  99% of the time is spent in the meaningless "Sending data" or one or two other cryptic phases.

One thing that may help some formulations:  `TEXT` is overkill for `country`; change it to a suitably short `VARCHAR`.  That will allow for a slightly faster way of dealing with any temp table.